# Adding a String Within a String in PHP

Tags: php, string, addition

I have a basic string question in PHP.

Let's say I have a variable `$story`:

```
$story = 'this story is titled and it is really good';
```

How would I go about adding a string after 'titled' and before 'and'?
If I had the title in a another variable, let say

```
$title = 'candy';
```

What function or method could I use to do this?

```
$story = 'this story is titled and it is really good';
$title = 'candy';
// do something
var_dump($story === 'this story is titled candy and it is really good'); // TRUE
```

Comment: read the string section in the manual, this is basic php http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options.

```
$title = 'candy';
$story = 'this story is titled '.$title.' and it is really good';
$story = "this story is titled $title and it is really good";
$story = sprintf('this story is titled %s and it is really good', $title);
```

See:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

If you are using php with html and want to print the string (outside of php tags)

```
this story is titled <?php echo $title ?> and it is really good
```

Comment: thanks for the simple explanation, i forgot to mention that i wanted to do it without creating a new variable. thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use double quotes and put the variable inside the string, like so:

```
$title = 'candy';
$story = "this story is titled $title and it is really good";
```

Comment: Also `$story = 'this story is titled ' . $title . ' and it is really good';
`

Comment: Hmm, I added that part to my comment before I saw this - now it has been removed?

Comment: this solution assumes that `$title` is defined before `$story`, which may not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a placeholder in your original string, and then replacing the placeholder with your title.

So, amend your code to be like this:

```
$story = "this story is titled {TITLE} and it is really good";
```

Then, you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace your placeholder with the actual title, like this:

```
$newStory = str_replace("{TITLE}", $title, $story);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be:

```
$story="this story is titled $title and it is really good".
```

If you're asking how to find where to insert, you could do something like this:

```
$i=stripos($story," and");
$story=substr($story,0,$i)." ".$title.substr($story,$i);
```

The third was is to place a token that's unlikely to appear in the text like ||TITLE||. Search for that and replace it with the title text like:

```
$i=stripos($story,"||TITLE||");
$story=substr($story,0,$i).$title.substr($story,$i+9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of your friend string interpolation (as [GreenWevDev said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073753/adding-a-string-within-a-string-in-php/5073763#5073763)).

Or if you need to replace the word `title` with a string, and only on its own, you can with regex.

```
$story = preg_replace('/\btitle\b/', $title, $story);
```